# information on accesing MTP devices in a Windows form application in C#

Tags: c#, mtp

I spend a lot of time on searching for examples of information on how to access MTP devices with C#. 
I didn't find anything, which could help me.
There are only examples for different languages or for Windows Store Applications. 
Is there something specific for Windows form applications in C#?